# Wordpress how to get the output before the header in the templates using header.php

Tags: php, wordpress

**Requirement:**
I have a following script to locked the Wordpress pages. It is working fine when I applied on a specific template. So instead of adding the script on 17 different templates, I put it on the **header.php** file using `!is_front_page()` statement so script should work on all pages except the homepage.

**Problem:** The script only work if I put it on the very top of the page at line number 1 without any space, otherwise it throwing error (Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers).

**Error Reason in my case:**  As I mentioned earlier, that I put the following script in header.php file. So error is showing up because of this line `<?php get_header(); ?>` which is in the templates file (and following code must be before of the `<php get_header(); ?>`. So my question is, is there any turnaround that we can do with the following script or I need to put the script on all templates manually on the first line?

```
 <?php
      if(!is_user_logged_in())
      $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . urlencode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
      wp_redirect( $redirect );
 ?>
```

Comment: As soon as any output happens, the connection changes from sending 'header' information to sending 'body' information. Redirecting uses header information to tell the user's browser that the page can actually be found somewhere else. As such, you can only redirect the user before any of the body gets output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this in your functions.php - hooking your code into a WordPress hook so it fires before the header is called etc... This means it gets called on every page as well.

```
function password_protected() {
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $redirect = home_url() . '/wp-login.php?redirect_to=' . urlencode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
        wp_redirect( $redirect );
    }
}
add_action('init', 'password_protected');
```

Updated thanks to @rnevius

Comment: The `init` or `parse_request` hook would be even more appropriate (and faster). No need to hook more than once.